# Can I install nasm and run .asm codes on Windows Subsystem Linux(WSL) for Ubuntu terminal on windows?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've been avoiding to dual boot my new Laptop to use Ubuntu yet, and I've got some assembly codes to be run in the nasm. I recently stumbled upon this Ubuntu terminal for Windows, so my question is: can I install the nasm package and run .asm codes in this terminal?

**Edit:** The .asm code is being compiled (I wrote the "Hello World"  code as a test) with the following steps:

1. `nasm -f elf64 filename.asm`
2. `ld -o filename filename.o`
3. `./filename`

There is no output on the terminal, as it should display `Hello World`.

Here's the code for reference:

```
section .data

msg db "Hello World"
msglen equ $-msg

section .text
global _start
_start:

 mov rax,1
 mov rdi,1
 mov rsi,msg
 mov rdx,msglen

mov rax,60
mov rdx,0
syscall
```

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt install nasm`?

Comment: I just tried that and it worked for me, it's just that I am unaware of where to store the .asm codes or where can you write files from the Ubuntu terminal?

Comment: What are the contents of filename.asm? Please, [edit] your question and add all the information there, instead of using comments.

Comment: I've added the code for reference, I also checked that the executable a.out file is being generated but still nothing happens  when I call it with './a.out '@FedonKadifeli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You skipped a `syscall` in your code!

The `syscall` in the last line is used to exit the program. However, to display the string, you have to make another `syscall` after you fill the `rax`, `rdi`, `rsi`, and `rdx` registers.

The correct code is given below:

```
section .data

msg db "Hello World", 10
msglen equ $-msg

section .text
global _start
_start:

mov rax,1
mov rdi,1
mov rsi,msg
mov rdx,msglen
syscall

mov rax,60
mov rdx,0
syscall
```

I have also added a "new line" (ASCII decimal code `10`) to the end of your string, so that a new line is displayed after `Hello World` string.

Comment: Thank you very much it works! I just don't know why the program worked before on Ubuntu OS without that 
    syscall